# _vode.error: failed in processing argument list for call-back f

Tags: scipy, ode

I try to solve a series of ODEs by scipy integrate.ode module, what does this error message mean?

```
create_cb_arglist: Failed to build argument list (siz) with enough arguments (tot-opt) required by user-supplied function (siz,tot,opt=6,7,0).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/DeepSpillModel/api.py", line 49, in <module>
    model.solver(start_time, end_time)
  File "D:\DeepSpillModel\far_field.py", line 17, in solver
    far_model.simulate(self.parcels, self.initial_location, start_time,
  File "D:\DeepSpillModel\single_parcel_model.py", line 15, in simulate
    self.t, self.y = calculate_underwater(self.profile, parcel, t0, y0, diff_factor, self.p, delta_t_sub)
  File "D:\DeepSpillModel\single_parcel_model.py", line 44, in calculate_underwater
    r.integrate(t[-1] + delta_t, step=True)
  File "D:\Miniconda3\envs\gnome\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_ode.py", line 433, in integrate
    self._y, self.t = mth(self.f, self.jac or (lambda: None),
  File "D:\Miniconda3\envs\gnome\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_ode.py", line 1024, in step
    r = self.run(*args)
  File "D:\Miniconda3\envs\gnome\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_ode.py", line 1009, in run
    y1, t, istate = self.runner(*args)
_vode.error: failed in processing argument list for call-back f.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Your function `f` appears to expect 7 arguments, time, state and 5 parameters. Your provided data seems to have only 4 parameters. This is my interpretation of the error message, without code or further context, if possible reduced to a minimal example, one can not say much more.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I missed one argument.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Hello Sir, could you leave your email address? I have a couple of questions about solving ODEs with this package. I will appreciate it if you could help.